# How do I train the Convolutional Neural Network with negative and positive elements as the input of the first layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Just I am curious why I have to scale the testing set on the testing set, and not on the training set when I’m training a model on, for example, CNN?!
Or am I wrong? And I still have to scale it on the training set.
Also, can I train a dataset in the CNN that contents positive and negative elements as the first input of the network?
Any answers with reference will be really appreciated.

Comment: you scale both train and test data

Comment: I know that. My question is why should I scale the testing data on the testing data instead of the training data?

Answer (score 0):

Scaling data depends upon the requirement as well the feed/data you got. Test data gets scaled with Test data only, because **Test data don't have the Target variable** (one less feature in Test data). If we scale our Training data with new Test data, our model will not be able to correlate with any target variable and thus fail to learn. So the key difference is the existence of Target variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew the basic concepts of the answer,  but I have not found any references yet. Do you have any reference for the answer? Please. Also, do you have an answer to the second one? Thanks

Comment: Few worthy references that I could find are [Article1](https://dzone.com/articles/retraining-machine-learning-models), [Article2](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-journey-of-a-machine-learning-model-from-building-to-retraining-fe3a37c32307) and [Article3](https://medium.com/ibm-watson-data-lab/keeping-your-machine-learning-models-up-to-date-f1ead546591b) (kindly google for _retraining ML models_ for more references). For second one, kindly detail your question with more info on what you mean by positive/negative elements (that too being passed in a CNN?)

Answer (score 0):

We usually have 3 types of datasets for getting a model trained,

1. Training Dataset
2. Validation Dataset
3. Test Dataset

**Training Dataset**

This should be an evenly distributed data set which covers all varieties of data. If your train with more **epochs**, the model will get used to the training dataset and will only give proper proper prediction on the training dataset and this is called **Overfitting**. Only way to keep a check on overfitting is by having other datasets which the model has never been trained on.

**Validation Dataset**

This can be used fine tune model hyperparameters

**Test Dataset**

This is the dataset which the model has not been trained on has never been a part of deciding the hyperparameters and will give the reality of how the model is performing.

Answer (score 0):

If scaling and normalization is used, the testing set should use the same parameters used during training. 
A good answer that links to that: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27615/should-we-apply-normalization-to-test-data-as-well

Also, some models tend to require normalization and others do not. 
The Neural Network architectures are normally robust and might not need normalization.